# Fetching just the Key/id from a ReferenceProperty in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I could use a little help in AppEngine land...

Using the [Python] API I create relationships like this example from the docs:

```
class Author(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()

class Story(db.Model):
    author = db.ReferenceProperty(Author)

story = db.get(story_key)
author_name = story.author.name
```

As I understand it, that example will make two datastore queries. One to fetch the Story and then one to deference the Author inorder to access the name. But I want to be able to fetch the id, so do something like:

```
story = db.get(story_key)
author_id = story.author.key().id()
```

I want to *just* get the id from the reference. I do not want to have to deference (therefore query the datastore) the ReferenceProperty value.

From reading the documentation it says that

> the value of a ReferenceProperty is a Key

Which leads me to think that I could just call .id() on the reference's value. But it also says:

> The ReferenceProperty model provides features for Key property values such as automatic dereferencing.

I can't find anything that explains *when* this referencing takes place?
Is it safe to call .id() on the ReferenceProperty's value?
Can it be assumed that calling .id() will not cause a datastore lookup?

Comment: See [ReferenceProperty: .get_value_for_datastore() -> .get_key() - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-python/Ai90diACDiA) too

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Answering my own question for the sake of helping fellow searchers...

As suspected calling story.author.key().id() or even story.author.id() will result in datastore queries. The correct method [dictated by the API docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_get_value_for_datastore) is:

```
story = db.get(story_key)
author_id = Story.author.get_value_for_datastore(story).id()
```