# Google App Engine: Does calling .key().id() on a reference property trigger a get of that entity?

Tags: google-app-engine

If I have an object with a reference property, will calling the .key() or .key().id() method on the reference property cause it to be retrieved from the data store?  Or can I can I get the value from those without a request being triggered?

```
class MyObject(db.Model):
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty()

myObj = MyObject( reference = myOtherObject )
myObj.put()

# Will this retrieve the key without doing a get for the object?
temp1 = myObj.reference.key()

# What about this?
temp2 = myObj.reference.key().id()
```

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044121/fetching-just-the-key-id-from-a-referenceproperty-in-app-engine

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Accessing the property from the model instance will de-reference it (it will be fetched):

```
# This will retrieve the key after doing a get for the object.
temp1 = myObj.reference.key()
```

To get the key without de-referencing, use:

```
# This will retrieve the key without doing a get for the object.
temp1 = MyObject.reference.get_value_for_datastore(myObj)

# Then you get the id...
temp2 = temp1.id()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Accessing a always trigger a ReferenceProperty sub-query.

I usually store two more properties when using ReferenceProperty. When saving the reference model i also store a string representative of the key and a int of the id.

```
class MyObject(db.Model):
    reference = db.ReferenceProperty()
    referenceStrKey = db.StringProperty()
    referenceId = db.IntProperty()
```

Lately I only store the key as a string and then ad to properties:

```
class MyObject(db.Model):
    referenceStrKey = db.StringProperty()

    @property
    def reference(self):
        return RefModel.get(db.Key(self.referenceStrKey))

    @property
    def referenceId(self):
        return db.Key(self.referenceStrKey).id()
```

Comment: Storing the Key and ID separately is completely redundant since the `Key` is stored on the entity and the `id` can be derived from it. Turning  a single reference property into 3 different properties that have to updated manually is not worth the convenience of not having to use a `get_value_for_datastore`.

Comment: Also, in the example each time `.reference` is accessed it is fetched again (while `ReferenceProperty` caches it).

Comment: Also, it's not a 'sub query', it's a datastore get operation.